# Really slow For loop

Tags: vba, excel

How can I set my loop faster?

I have 4 columns and more than 250 rows and it takes like 5 minutes to loop this:

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Call CPU0

Dim TableA As Range:    Set TableA = Range("L_PriceA")

With TableA
LongA = TableA.Rows.Count
    For s = 1 To LongA
       .Cells(s, 3).Value = "dynamic"
       .Cells(s, 4).Value = "dynamic"
       .Cells(s, 5).Value = "dynamic"
       .Cells(s, 6).Value = "dynamic"
    Next
End With
```

"dynamic" will be data from xml because nobody helped me with [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27326684/vba-longer-url-slow-vba) and I don't know :/. Also looked at some loop problems here in stackO, but no main boost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looping over a range is slow.  Avoid it by moving your data to Variant Array, something like this:

```
Dim dat As Variant
Dim s As Long

With TableA
    LongA = .Rows.Count
    dat = .Value  ' TableA must be at least 6 columns wide
    For s = 1 To LongA
       dat(s, 3) = "dynamic"
       dat(s, 4) = "dynamic"
       dat(s, 5) = "dynamic"
       dat(s, 6) = "dynamic"
    Next
    TableA.Value = dat
End With
```

Comment: `dat(s, 3).Value = ` is a typo. You mean `dat(s, 3) = ` right?

Comment: @chris neilsen I have another problem, It seem that if I define larger area for Varriant Array it also check all cells for mistakes plus delete all my excel formulas any mistakes lead to 1004 error, can you tell me If is some way to keep my formulas in place, thank you.

Comment: @AlennG'Kar this is not how SO works.  If you have a new question, ask a _new question_